# Unavailable message in TestFlight Beta

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, xcode6, testflight

I am seeing "Unavailable" message in TestFLight Beta App in iOS8. Please find the attached screenshot, please tell me how to fix this issue.[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get this all the time.  In iTunes Connect, remove yourself as a tester, save, add yourself back, save, then open the beta build through the new invitation email you receive.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the same version (i.e 2.4.1) your'e testing was not approved to sale. When a version is approved for sale by Apple, it becomes unavailable for testing. Upload a new version (with a higher version number) to TestFlight

Answer (score 1):

I'm suffering this problem and the solution I've found is:

1. Upload a new build.
2. Activate TestFlight for it.
3. Deactivate TestFlight.
4. Activate it again.

It's totally absurd but it works.

Comment: Yes, happend to me many times already. Just deactivate and activate again until the build appears in TestFlight.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it is my solution for this:

1. Remove all of "Internal Testers" for this app in iTunes Connect -> Prerelease -> Internal Testers and click Save.
2. Turn off "TestFlight Beta Testing" in iTunes Connect -> Prerelease -> Builds.
3. Turn on "TestFlight Beta Testing".
4. Re-invite "Internal Testers".

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

After publishing live, then uploading a new version the list of testers is empty. On the testflight menu in iTunes Connect, go to Internal testing (Testflight/Internal Testing) and click 'select version to test' and then 'Start Testing'. Seems that changing version numbers (e.g. 3.4 to 3.5) resets the binary to use.