# TestFlight unavailable

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I have uploaded a couple of apps, a couple of times to TestFlight and it has always worked. With this new app I did the same and it appears on tester's device as expected:

[image]

The problem is when the they try to download it this message appear:

[image]

And when they tap on the app instead of install, it looks like this:

[image]

The "funny" part is that when you tap on any other app in testflight, it would look like the last picture, **but** it would let you download it.

Does anyone know what's happening and how to fix it? Thanks for your time

**P.S**

I tried the following solutions but nothing changed:

- [Unavailable message in TestFlight Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393823/unavailable-message-in-testflight-beta)
- [iOS 8 TestFlight does not install app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267449/ios-8-testflight-does-not-install-app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testflight is broken right now. Wait until apple fixes it, but the issue can't be resolved right now. Apple status pages haven't acknowledged the downtime yet.

Comment: Hi! How do you know? Is there any official announcement?

Comment: Down again!? Go home testflight, you're drunk :)

Answer (score 2):

All is good, don't worry: 
https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/

This is all your imagination!:
http://www.macrumors.com/2015/05/07/testflight-itunes-connect-down-may-2015/

http://www.slashgear.com/testflight-is-currently-down-beta-apps-in-holding-pattern-07382512/

http://thenextweb.com/insider/2015/05/07/apples-testflight-service-is-currently-experiencing-an-outage/

http://appleinsider.com/articles/15/05/07/testflight-beta-testing-platform-down-since-wednesday-developers-say

Comment: just added another one :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try recreating your provisioning profile:**

1. Log in to Apple Developer
2. Delete your provisioning profiles for the app in question
3. Recreate the provisioning profiles
4. Open Xcode
5. On the top menu, open Preferences, then the Accounts tab
6. Highlight your account and click 'View Details'
7. It will bring up a list of all your provisioning profiles, click the refresh in the lower-left
8. Update your provisioning profile in the Build Settings
9. Recompile and re-upload

Comment: In this case, testflight is really down :p

Comment: I saw :-) Too bad, thought Apple had it ironed out.

Comment: Yeah :/, [social media](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23TestFlight) is quite useful in these cases to see if its you or everybody

Answer (score 0):

Just need to recompiled and upload new build. it should be good.